xUnit fixture with IAsyncLifetime not working as intendend
I am creating integration tests for a .net project with TestContainers and xUnit.
I need to add a user in each test so that I can perform an authorized request. For this I create a public class BaseRuntimeTest : IClassFixture<RuntimeTestWebAppFactory>, IDisposable, IAsyncLifetime .
BaseRuntimeTest then implements:
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await AddAdminUserAsync(Factory.CreateClient());
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DeleteAdminUserAsync(Factory.CreateClient());
    }

This BaseRuntimeTest class is then extended by my integration test class (I only have one test class at the moment, so I believe the default xUnit behavior should be sequentially tests and not parallel). Below you can see two of the tests that I have:
public class AccountTests(RuntimeTestWebAppFactory factory) : BaseRuntimeTest(factory)
{
    private readonly AccountHelper _accountHelper = new();

    private readonly Fixture _fixture = new();

    [Fact]
    public async Task Accounts_GetAll_WhenMultipleAccountsExist_ReturnsAll_200()
    {
        // Arrange
        var accounts = new List<Account>
        {
            _accountHelper.CreateAccount(_fixture.Create<Guid>()),
            _accountHelper.CreateAccount(_fixture.Create<Guid>())
        };
        await ArrangeAccountRegistryAsync(accounts);

        // Act
        var response = await AdminAuthorizedClientHttp.GetAsync($"{Constants.Application.GetRuntimeApiUrl()}/accounts");

        // Assert
        var jArray = JArray.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        jArray.Should().HaveCount(accounts.Count);
        ((int)response.StatusCode).Should().Be(200);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Accounts_GetAll_WhenNoAccountExist_ReturnsEmpty_200()
    {
        // Arrange
        await ArrangeAccountRegistryAsync([]);

        // Act
        var response = await AdminAuthorizedClientHttp.GetAsync($"{Constants.Application.GetRuntimeApiUrl()}/accounts");

        // Assert
        var jArray = JArray.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        jArray.Should().BeEmpty();
        ((int)response.StatusCode).Should().Be(200);
    }

If I run all tests only one passes, and the others fail due to the User already existing on the database, meaning that DisposeAsync did not delete the User in time.
If I run all tests in debug, I see that the order of execution is as intendend, and it seems that they all pass since I am stopping on the breakpoints giving it more time to run...
It looks like the DisposeAsync is still executing while the next test is starting to run. Am I missing something?

Are you running multiple tests in parallel?

@julealgon I only have one test class, so I believe the default xUnit behavior should be sequentially

Seems strange! Please share the test class as well.

@sa-es-ir added it to the question

Can you create a class-level property for HttpClient and only call Factory.CreateClient() once.

Yes, xUnit per default runs the Tests sequentially (if they are in the same test class).
If you have 2 test-classes they run in parallel (but I think only if the tests are asynchronous Tasks). If they share a collection and you dont want both test-classes to run tests in parallel, theres the Collection Attribute for the class with a self defined name.
Does Factory.CreateClient() maybe runs asynchronous code that isn't being awaited properly?
Have you tried putting a await Task.Delay(5000) for example after the end of the first running test (so ideally in the DisposeAsync) to see if there really is a timing problem and have you set proper breakpoints to check?
I have worked with xUnit and TestContainers quite a lot and as long as I've awaited everything properly in the Init and DisposeAsync I've never had problems so far. Doesnt matter if I worked with a PostgreSQL image, or a mongoDB image or anything similar.
I once had timing problems with starting a TestContainer properly where code execution sometimes started before the Container was up and running... might this be an Issue? Its not clear if you start your TestContainer prior to every single test or before executing the whole TestClass.

You can always disable parallel execution of unit tests by putting such attribute:
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]

as mentioned in xUnit docs.

I have run into a similar issue and perhaps it is the case for you as well. Inside of my base class for my integration tests I created my test containers (sql server) and loaded it's connection string into an environment variable scoped to the process with the idea that it would be an separate one per class.
When running all my tests together I had a failure for duplicate entries and the cause of this was due to the way I was setting my environment variables, the environment variables were scoped to the process so every time my tests ran in parallel it would override the same environment variable value which meant that the different classes was using the same connection string.
To fix this you can simply use prefix when setting your environment variables and when adding them to IConfiguration just add one's with the same prefix:
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configuration) =>
    {
        configuration.Sources.Clear();
        var path = Path.Join(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "appsettings.integrationtest.json");
        configuration.AddJsonFile(path);

        // Prefix is used to avoid conflicts with other tests since the environment variables are stored in the process and there is only one process executing all tests
        var prefix = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}:";

        var applicationDatabaseConnectionString = GetApplicationDatabaseConnectionString(); // Get connection string from the test container

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable($"{prefix}Database__ConnectionString",
            applicationDatabaseConnectionString,
            EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: prefix);
    });
}

